# Vuetify tabs not working with masonry.js, any fixes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, vuetify.js, masonry

I'm trying to build a photo gallery with vuetify and masonry.js
I want to have multiple tabs, and for the images inside the tabs to be in a masonry layout.
For this I'm using masonry.js, and for the tabs I'm using vuetify.
The thing is, masonry.js is only laying out the initial tab properly, but not the other tabs.
(I think this is because of the fact that the other tabs aren't loaded so window.onload() doesn't work)
I tried making it so that when you click on each tab, the function bellow get's called again (by giving the component a method handleMason() ), but it's not working as I would be expecting.

```
window.onload = () => {
  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  const masonry = new Masonry(grid, {
    itemSelector: ".grid-item",
    columnWidth: ".grid-sizer",
    fitWidth: true,
  });
```

```
methods: {
    handleMason() {
      console.log("Handled");

      const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
      var masonry = new Masonry(grid, {
        itemSelector: ".grid-item",
        columnWidth: ".grid-sizer",
        fitWidth: true,
      });
    },
  },
```

I know that handleMason() is called because the console.log works. But the rest of the function doesn't style the images properly.
Apologies in advance for the crappy question, first time asking anything here ^^

**EDIT**

I've created a repo to illustrate the problem:

https://github.com/Hi-Im-Jony/masonry-gallery/tree/master

The site is also deployed using netlify at:

https://flamboyant-almeida-7a9bd0.netlify.app/

Comment: Can you provide a codepen ?

Comment: @Philx94 I'm afraid I'm too dumb to make the codepen work with Vue, so I created a repo to illustrate the problem. It is at github.com/Hi-Im-Jony/masonry-gallery/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up on using masonry.js, as vue-stack-grid served a similar enough purpose and worked in the tabs